# Appium is unable to identify any element on particular page of My Mobile native app

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, android-uiautomator, appium-android

[appium logs 2nd part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mXhX.png)

[appium logs first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXixr.png)

[UI Automator showing element properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u11th.png)

[UI Automator showing all element properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5gaW.png)

**Summary:**

Appium is unable to identify any element on particular page of My Mobile native app. I have used all the possible locators for different elements shown on that page with help of UI Automate Viewer.

1. Used different locators (by `id`/`xpath`/`contains`/`accessibility`/`UIAutomate`).
2. Verified that the page belongs to native app only with no Web View.
3. applied different types of sufficient wait for the page.
4. `driver.get.pagesource` not working for the page.

Can any one please help in same, the below ways I have opted for finding the solutions but nothing has worked till now.

Comment: When you say ` unable to identify elements` - what is the exact error that is being thrown. Also if you can add a screenshot of the element tree and the tried locators, that would help in debugging.

Comment: Thank u for reply.Please find the below required details.

Comment: Please refer the issue details where I have attached required screenshots of error and elements details.

Answer (score 0):

You say a `native` apps, but seen from the picture, that you facing with like a `Maps` application (this is web apps, my assumse), often in testing things like this happen, like you have to do a `switch context`. When you are on this page please try this :

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_1");
```

And this is for switch again to `native` :

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

Please read [this](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) reference and [this](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply!!I have verified that the page belongs to native app by 'layout option' in Developer Option in Mobile. Also verified the same by using driver.getcontext which showing value as Native_App.